# Critiques welcome on this posting

Tags: discussion

About one week ago I posted this [*question*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1150719/coefficient-of-foureir-cosine-value-of-full-series), but unfortunately I got only comment from one single person and no response, even though I luckily got one up-vote and I was able to get my question solved. What was wrong with my posting?

To avoid this question becomes too broad, I have this multiple-choice:

(1) Your question is way too long, you should have considered breaking it down into two nice tidy parts in the first place. Remember heavyweights have lives too, typing up LaTex is tedious and time-consuming, especially for those crazy PDE formulas. People got turned off by your long question!

(2) Your question is way too basic and simple, nobody got interested. People get intrigued by challenging question.

(3) PDE has few followers here in this MSE-land. Sorry!

(4) Your launching time, about morning US continental time, was unfortunate. All heavyweights and black-belts are pretty much occupied at that time slot. And by the end of the day, your question has staled.

(5) None of the above. Your posting was OK, you just had a bad day. Good luck next time!

Thank you for your time and critiques!

Comment: If I would have seen it, I would have answered but you say you already answered it so you can post the solution now.

Comment: Looks like I had missed you, seems like (5) is correct.

Comment: There are no crazy PDE formulas, since your question is not really about PDEs.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The closest answer is (5), followed by (3). It's an okay question, not too exciting. It's well structured, so length is not a problem: it's easy to see what the question is, and what you've done so far to solve it.

Statistics on [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) questions (note that "unanswered" means questions with no upvoted or accepted answers):

```
Last 7 Days     66.7% unanswered
Last 30 Days    56.5% unanswered
```

Statistics on [fourier-series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fourier-series) questions -- the tag you should have added.

```
Last 7 Days     76.9% unanswered
Last 30 Days    52.7% unanswered
```

Good luck with your next [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) question -- you'll need it.

Comment: Any ideas why math.se gets so few PDE experts?

Comment: Maybe purists don't want to mix with applied?